# Drawing (multifractals) of any specified dimension

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

How could anyone draw or plot fractals with a given Haussdorf non-intenger dimension?

Examples: D=0.5
          D=1/3

Answer (score 0):

You can tailor an [Iterated Function System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system) to produce compact stes of any fractal dimension (up to the dimension of the surrounding space)  The dimension can be controlled via the scaling factors of the single mappings.